# Programatically access OBIEE chart/ report and include it in an external web application page

Tags: apache, api, obiee

How to access and display OBIEE chart/report in my web application Page programatically?

Using the GO URL, im able to open a individual chart/report in a browser. I want to include the same chart/report as a part of my application page(inside a div).

when i send request to the GO URL via java httpclient i received a reply saying “Your browser is not supported by Oracle BI Presentation Services.”

i was failed when trying to send the request through AJAX.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I realize I may be adding some input a bit late for you, but I was able to bypass the browser compatibility issue by including the below line:

```
con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
```

However, I now get an HTML login page as a response, when I in fact expect an XML. (I use FORMAT=XML in my GO URL.). Haven't gotten past this, but I figured the code above may be able to help you if in fact this is still an issue.